Does lebesgue measurable function not lebesgue integrable on every closed interval exist?
I am trying to solve this exercise:
Let $f$ be a lebesgue measurable on the line. if for any $r \in \mathbb{Q}$, $f(x+r) = f(x)$$  (a.e. x)$. Prove that there exist a constant $C$, such that $f = C (a.e.)$
I try to use the theorem that if $f$ is lebesgue integrable on $[a, b]$, then almost every point in $[a, b]$ is a lebesgue point, that is $\lim_{h_1+h_2\to 0}\frac{1}{h_1+h_2}\int_{x_0-h_1}^{x_0+h_2}|f(x)-f(x_0)|dx=0$ for $h_1\ge0, h_2\ge0, h=h_1+h_2\neq0 $ $a.e. x \in [a, b]$.
To prove that the function $f$ is integrable on every interval, I just need to prove that the function is integrable on some closed interval. So the question is: does lebesgue measurable function not lebesgue integrable on every closed interval exist?
Is this method to prove the exercise workable? Or how can I solve the exercise?

If you want to use your method, consider instead $$f_n(x) = \max(-n, \min(n, f(x))$$ for sufficiently large $n$.  It will be integrable.

@Brian Moehring  Yes, I understand now! Thank you very much! (I was stuck in proving that the $f$ in the exercise is integrable.)  And may I ask whether there are other methods to solve this exercise?

Yes. Define a measurable function $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{x}\mathcal{X}_{(0,1]}(x).$$
Let $\{r_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and define $f_n(x):=\frac{1}{2^n}g(x-r_n)$. Put $f=\sup_n f_n$. Then $f$ is measurable and isn't integrable on any interval. The only issue is that it might take on the value $\infty$. To remedy this, note that for $k\in \mathbb{N}$,
$$A_k:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: f(x)> k\} \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty \{x\in \mathbb{R}: f_n(x)>k\},$$
and $\mu(\{x\in \mathbb{R}: f_n(x)>k\})=\frac{1}{k2^n}$. Hence $\mu(A_k)\leq \frac{1}{k}$. Since $A_\infty:=f^{-1}(\{\infty\})\subseteq \bigcap\limits_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ we conclude that $\mu(A_\infty)=0$. Then we can modify $f$ to be something finite, say $0$, on $A_\infty$ and the integral on any interval stays the same. The result is a finite, measurable function which isn't integrable on any interval.

Thank you! This function is very clever and it is constructed from $g$. And I want to think further: can I prove the function in the exercise which has periods of any rational numbers is integrable in an easy way? In other words why can't this function not integrable in any closed interval?
